# How to construct square of pairwise difference from a vector in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, vectorization, tensor, pairwise

I have a 1D vector having N dimension in TensorFlow,

how to construct sum of a pairwise squared difference?

### Example

**Input Vector**
`[1,2,3]`
**Output**
`6`
**Computed As**

```
(1-2)^2+(1-3)^2+(2-3)^2.
```

if I have input as an N-dim vector l, the output should be sigma_{i,j}((l_i-l_j)^2).

**Added question**: if I have a 2d matrix and want to perform the same process for each row of the matrix, and then average the results from all the rows, how can I do it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For pair-wise difference, subtract the `input` and the transpose of `input` and take only the upper triangular part, like:

```
pair_diff = tf.matrix_band_part(a[...,None] - 
                      tf.transpose(a[...,None]), 0, -1)
```

Then you can square and sum the differences.

Code:

```
a = tf.constant([1,2,3])
pair_diff = tf.matrix_band_part(a[...,None] - 
                      tf.transpose(a[...,None]), 0, -1)
output = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(pair_diff))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(output))
  # 6
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! May I ask what "a[...,None]" means?

Comment: same as `expand_dims(a,1)` ,` a` now becomes (3,1)

Comment: Thank you a lot, vijay! If the input is a 2d matrix, and I want to perform the same process on each row of the matrix, then average the results, how can I do? Many thanks!!!