# How to construct square of pairwise difference for each row vector in a matrix in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matrix

I have a 2D tensor having K*N dimension in TensorFlow,

For each row vector in the tensor, having N dimension, I can calculate the square of pairwise difference using the approach in [How to construct square of pairwise difference from a vector in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015563/how-to-construct-square-of-pairwise-difference-from-a-vector-in-tensorflow)

However, I need to average the results of the K row vectors: performing each vector's square of pairwise difference and averaging the results.

How can I do? Need your help, many thanks!!!

Comment: Perhaps you should add the [tag:numpy] tag to your question for increased exposure (if it applies).

Answer (score 0):

The code and then the run results:

```
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[2,5,6]])
a = tf.expand_dims(a,1)
at = tf.transpose(a, [0,2,1])
pair_diff = tf.matrix_band_part( a - at, 0, -1)
output = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(pair_diff), axis=[1,2])
final = tf.reduce_mean(output)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(a - at))
    print(sess.run(output))
    print(sess.run(final))
```

Give this results:

1) `a - at` (computes the same thing of the link you posted but rowise)

```
 [[[ 0  1  2]
   [-1  0  1]
   [-2 -1  0]]

 [[ 0  3  4]
  [-3  0  1]
  [-4 -1  0]]]
```

2) `output` (take the matrix band part and sum all dimensions apart from rows, i.e. you have the result of the code you posted for each row)

```
[ 6 26]
```

3) `final` Average among rows

```
16
```

Comment: Hi Guiseppe, thank you. I have tested the results with x same as mu as [[1.,2.,3.],[2.,3.,5.],[3.,4.,5.]], here K==N==3, but the results is not 26. Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: Edited. Look if it suits to you now

Answer (score 0):

Similar logic to [How to construct square of pairwise difference from a vector in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015563/how-to-construct-square-of-pairwise-difference-from-a-vector-in-tensorflow/51016946#51016946) but some changes required to handle 2d:

```
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3], [4, 6, 8]])
pair_diff = tf.transpose(a[...,None, None,] - tf.transpose(a[...,None,None,]), [0,3,1,2])

reshape_diff = tf.reshape(tf.matrix_band_part(pair_diff, 0, -1), [-1, tf.shape(a)[1]*tf.shape(a)[1]])
output = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(reshape_diff),1)[::tf.shape(a)[0]+1]

with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(output))
#[ 6 24]
```

Comment: Hi Vijay, thank you a lot, this however seems complex to me, can the code generalise to K dimensions?

Comment: yes i tested for a longer one than shown above. You can test yourself. Try to print output of each step, you will get it.